# guzzle undefined function getStatusCode()

Tags: php, guzzle

My code is as follows:

```
require_once $DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

...

if($token!='' && $email!='')
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/sendmail', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true'
        ],
        'body' => $email
    ]);
    if($response.getStatusCode() === 201) {
        exit('<h1>Email sent, check your inbox</h1>');
    } else {
        exit('<h2>There was an error sending the email.</h2> Status code: ' . $response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

I keep getting an error **Call to undefined function getStatusCode()**.
I know I need to add another use, but I have tried everything and can't get it to work, same error every time.

Comment: try $response->getStatusCode()  (arrow instead of dot)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  Copied the code from Microsoft, it is supposed to be:

```
if($response->getStatusCode() === 202)
```

Also it is 202 not 201 for success

Comment: Actually, anything 2XX is considered a successful response